# Text color in natural table heading in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

I'm new to ConTeXt and having a problem with colors of header in a "natural table". I want to have the text in the header displayed as white, and not gray. Here is what I have right now

```
\setuppapersize[letter]
\language[fr]
\setupbodyfont[12pt,ss]
\enableregime[utf]
\setupcolors[state=start]
\definecolor[white][r=1,g=1,b=1]
\definecolor[darkblue][r=.22,g=.42,b=.52]
\definecolor[grayWriting][r=.31,g=.31,b=.31]
\definecolor[grayPale][r=.92,g=.94,b=.95]
\definecolor[graySub][r=.75,g=.83,b=.87]

\starttext
\startcolor[grayWriting]
\setuphead[subject][style=bold,14pt,rm]
\subject{Subject}
\setupTABLE[row][even]
[background=color,backgroundcolor=white,frame=off]
\setupTABLE[row][odd]
[background=color,backgroundcolor=grayPale,frame=off]
\setupTABLE[header][each]
[background=color,backgroundcolor=darkblue,textcolor=white,style=bold]
\setupTABLE[c][each][width=.25\textwidth]
\bTABLE[frame=off,align=right,split=repeat,option=stretch]% head on every page,
\bTABLEhead
\bTR
\bTH ~ \eTH
\bTH H2 \eTH
\bTH H3 \eTH
\bTH H4 \eTH
\eTR
\eTABLEhead
\bTABLEnext % setup for next table head
\bTR
\bTH ~ \eTH
\bTH H2 \eTH
\bTH H3 \eTH
\bTH H4 \eTH
\eTR
\eTABLEnext
\bTABLEbody
\bTR
\bTD 1 \eTD
\bTD 2 \eTD
\bTD 3 \eTD
\bTD 4 \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD 1 \eTD
\bTD 2 \eTD
\bTD 3 \eTD
\bTD 4 \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD 1 \eTD
\bTD 2 \eTD
\bTD 3 \eTD
\bTD 4 \eTD
\eTR
\bTR
\bTD 1 \eTD
\bTD 2 \eTD
\bTD 3 \eTD
\bTD 4 \eTD
\eTR
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives an output of 
[image: output]

Any help would be appreciated. I know that I could write `{\color[white] H1}` in my heading cells, but I really want to avoid it.

Comment: OT: If you want to change the text color of the entire document, use `\setupcolors[textcolor=grayWriting]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
\setupTABLE[header][each][...,foregroundcolor=white,...]
```

[image]