# change header style in natural tables

Tags: context

I am using natural tables to design key to symbols for my geography presentations.

I set a big bodyfont (Latin Modern 18pt, S4 paper) to make sure every pupil will be able to read. This is however oversized when it comes to key to symbols.
I was able to resize table contents to `\tfxx` but I have troubles with resizing the header section to `\bfxx`. I could of course enclose each header in a {\tfxx }, but I am looking for a global solution.
 After reading [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165124/text-color-in-natural-table-heading-in-context) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58320/formatting-natural-table-header-with-context), I tried this, but failed.

```
\setuppaper[S4]
\setupbodyfont[18pt]

\starttext
\setupTABLE[frame=off,style=\tfxx]
\setupTABLE[column][1,3][align={middle,lohi},loffset=0.3cm,roffset=0.2cm,toffset=0cm,boffset=0cm]
\setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[column][4][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft]
\setupTABLE[header][each][style=\bfxx]

\bTABLE
\bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. Un espace enclavé  \eTH \bTH[nc=2]II. Une ZUP \eTH \eTR
\bTR \bTD  \eTD \bTD autoroute \eTD \bTD  \eTD \bTD grands ensembles \eTD \eTR

\eTABLE 
\stoptext
```

I tried under ConTeXt TL 2017 and with online ConTeXt garden.

PS : this doesn't solve my fontsize issue, but it looks like the header line is not properly closed. If I put a frame, it won't close. It will with

```
\bTR \bTH I. \eTH \bTH Un espace enclavé \eTH  \eTH \bTH II. \eTH  \bTH Une ZUP \eTH \eTR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `headstyle`. To use the setup option `header` you need to mark the header as header by `\bTABLEhead...\eTABLEhead`.

[image: headstyle]

```
\setuppaper[S4]
\setupbodyfont[18pt]

\starttext
\setupTABLE[frame=off,style=\tfxx]
\setupTABLE[column][1,3][align={middle,lohi},loffset=0.3cm,roffset=0.2cm,toffset=0cm,boffset=0cm]
\setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[column][4][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft]
\setupTABLE[header][each][headstyle=\bfxx]

\bTABLE
\bTABLEhead
\bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. Un espace enclavé  \eTH \bTH[nc=2]II. Une ZUP \eTH \eTR
\eTABLEhead
\bTABLEbody
\bTR \bTD  \eTD \bTD autoroute \eTD \bTD  \eTD \bTD grands ensembles \eTD \eTR
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE 
\stoptext
```

---

Alternative (less verbose):

```
\setuppaper[S4]
\setupbodyfont[18pt]

\starttext
\setupTABLE[frame=off,style=\tfxx,headstyle=\bfxx]
\setupTABLE[column][1,3][align={middle,lohi},loffset=0.3cm,roffset=0.2cm,toffset=0cm,boffset=0cm]
\setupTABLE[column][2][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[column][4][width=0.4 \textwidth]
\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft]

\bTABLE
\bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. Un espace enclavé  \eTH \bTH[nc=2]II. Une ZUP \eTH \eTR
\bTR \bTD  \eTD \bTD autoroute \eTD \bTD  \eTD \bTD grands ensembles \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE 
\stoptext
```